# XQuery: How to output string literal & in value of attribute

Tags: xquery, basex

test.xqy:

```
element test
{
  attribute haha {"&amp;"}
}
```

command line:

```
$ basex test.xqy
<test haha="&amp;"/>
```

And I need the output to be: `<test haha="&"/>`. The XML entity is not processed by BaseX?

Comment: Why do you need the output to be ill-formed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document `<test haha="&"/>` is not well-formed, so there’s no chance to get this output with BaseX or any other XML processor. However, the value of haha is indeed '&'; you will see this if you return the attribute value as string:

```
string(<test haha="&amp;"/>/@haha)
```